# jQuery Bootstrap works in Firefox but not IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion

I am running jQuery 2.1 and bootstrap 3.2 my code works in firefox but does not work in IE10. I am thinking that it has something to do with compatability mode so I have tried adding 
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` to the header... which still did not fix anything.

The docs say IE10 should be find that's why I do not understand what is going on and am assuming there is something I can write in the code to make it work. Even the placeholders for ColdFusion will not appear..

```
<cfinput 
  type="text" 
  name="firstname_#Add#" 
  placeholder="First"  
  validateat="onSubmit" 
  validate="noblanks" >
<cfinput 
  type="text" 
  name="middlename_#Add#"  
  placeholder="Middle">
```

Below is an example that works in Firefox but not IE10.
http://jsfiddle.net/hwcu7e05/5/

This is what the top of my page looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/formactions.js"></script>
<link href="../../../stylesTitles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../../js/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../../js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="../../../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../../../js/myjquery.js"></script>
<script src="../../../js/formfeecalculations.js"></script>
<script src="../../../js/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../js/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
   body { background-image: url("/images/bg_skyblue.jpg"); }
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: **How** does it not work? Are there errors in the developer console? What is supposed to happen?

Comment: There are no `<input type=text>` fields in the fiddle you linked.

Comment: I am having similar issues, I am glad you brought this up!

Comment: The linked fiddle works fine for me in IE10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need `CFFORM`, `CFINPUT`, etc. if you want to take advantage of CF's built-in client-side validation. Since you're trying to do something modern, get rid of the `CFFORM` code and just do simple `FORM` elements. Odds are, some of the ColdFusion generated JavaScript is interfering with jQuery and jQuery Validate in certain situations.